# Is it possible to have multiple builds of the same application on TestFlight?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Is it possible to have multiple builds of the same application available on test flight, so that different user can download only builds for which they have been invited?

Also, right now, only build is what should be changed. If this is not possible, is there some way to accomplish this with a different setup ? (some setting in iTunesConnect or to setup an app differently)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do it, but you have another way,

"Best way to distribute ipa to client is to upload ipa & provisioning profile to [www.diawi.com](http://www.diawi.com) and generate link. You have to send this link to client and client can install ipa in his device by opening generated link in his device's safari and then by clicking install application. Note that provisioning profile must include client's device UDID."

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137569/distribute-ipa-to-client)

Comment: Actually, I know that this is possible, like you mentioned in one part of your answer, and that is to manually install ipa  to appropriate tester. That all goes well (I know about a bit different method than yours but it is possible), but I was just wondering is something like this supported at all through Test Flight.